# Vote limit reached? But I haven't voted today...

Tags: support, votes

So this is awkward. I just tried to upvote a question, and it said I reached my limit for the day. Only thing is, I haven't upvoted yet today!

Strangely enough, I reached my vote limit yesterday before I hit 40 (was only at 38) so perhaps it's related.

Anyone else run into this, perhaps on another site?

Answer (score 1):

The sites are based on UTC time.  In order to see the UTC time, hover over your name at the top of the page and look at the bottom of the popup that appears.

It is just about the end of the day UTC.  Is it possible the difference between your timezone and UTC is the issue?

Comment: Seems unlikely. I hit the vote limit (of 38) yesterday around 2300 UTC. I didn't attempt to cast a single vote until shortly before I made this post.